# Inconsistent result of MATLAB regex

Tags: regex, matlab

I have some string separated by pipe (and period) that I tried to split using MATLAB regex that is:

```
m = 'mari|bersenang|senang.jpg';
```

In the first step I split that string by pipe so at the end there is a string `senang.jpg`. In the second step, I split this string by period. But the result different from what I got in the first step. In the first step the output just a cell that contains string. But in second step, there is cell inside cell to wrap the outpout from regex function. I dont understand how this happen? Because if I split string `senang.jpg` directly (not from the output of regex function in the first step) the output just look normal.

This is my complete script:

```
clear all ;
clc;

m = 'mari|bersenang|senang.jpg'; 
hasil = regexp(m, '\|', 'split');
hasil %  result a cell 

test = hasil(end)
hasil = regexp(test, '\.', 'split'); 
hasil  % result a cell inside a cell 
hasil{1} % result a cell
hasil{1}{2} % get content of a cell 

test = 'senang.JPG'; 
hasil = regexp(test, '\.', 'split'); 
hasil % output just a cell
```

note: I using MATLAB 2009a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

> `test = hasil(end)`

by

```
test = hasil{end}; %// note curly braces
```

That way `test` is a string, not a cell containing a string.